# What are 'Azure Websites' called now?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I can't find Azure Websites on the [portal](https://portal.azure.com). I am using the portal after a few years now. They used to be called Azure Websites. What are they called now? Where can I find them?

Comment: Googling "Azure Websites", the 1st non sponsored result led me to the right info page.

Comment: FYI the name was changed nearly 4 years ago. Your question title comes off sounding like a rant. Further: The `azure-web-sites` tag itself (that you added to this question) calls out the updated name in its description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called App Services:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/app-service/

Obviously they have evolved in functionality as well as changing the name. You now have:

- Web Apps (this bit is the nearest equivalent to the old Azure Websites)
- Web App for containers
- Mobile App Services
- API Aps

There are quite a few other related festures to for analytics, serverless function, CI/CD etc.

Comment: Thank you. 11 minutes more. Where can I find something that used to be called *Cloud Service*?

Comment: @WaterCoolerv2 Cloud Services still exist, they're now "Cloud Services (classic)" - FWIW the search on the portal is pretty good now, it's easy to find stuff.